# Is there a use for 'Replenishment of the Flesh'?

Tags: world-of-darkness, werewolf-the-apocalypse, werewolf-20th-anniversary

In the W20 Changing Breeds book, on page 66, there's this Anansi gift:

> **Replenishment of the Flesh (Level Two)** — The Ananasi may summon
>   spiders and insects to join with her flesh, healing her. She devours
>   the insects, and assimilates the spiders.
>
> **System**: The player spends  one Gnosis point per non-aggravated health level healed. The Ananasi may take no other actions during a turn when she uses this Gift.

As Anansi can heal non aggravated damage using their Blood Pool (see below) is there any other use for this gift?

It appears that Replenishment of the Flesh is only of any use if the Anansi is out of blood pool but not gnosis which seems rather poor for a level two gift because otherwise it's a waste of points unless I'm missing something? Under Healing in the Changing Breeds book on page 60 it states:

> To heal bashing and lethal damage, Damhàn spend one blood point per
>   level of damage, and the healing takes one turn. In order to heal one
>   level of aggravated damage, an Ananasi must spend a total of five
>   blood points, at a rate of one point per turn. The aggravated damage
>   is healed at the end of the turn in which the last blood point is
>   spent.

Comment: The quoted segment is either incomplete or poorly written. Damhan refers specifically to the corrupted Anansi.

Comment: p58 of the Changing Breeds book, under the entry 'Lexicon', states 'Damhan (DOM-Hahn): The name which the Anansi call themselves'. I assume there's a difference between the various versions and the OP is quoting from the Onyx Path book specifically

Answer (score 3):

A patient or careful Anansi can use it because Gnosis restores without conspicuous resources.

But mostly here's the rub: According to **Page 400**

> An Ananasi can only spend one blood point per turn

So the gift allows you to heal completely in one turn if you have the Gnosis, where even ten blood points only gets you one level of health.  Not only that, but the other form of regeneration in Crawlerling form is to happen upon spiders and absorb them.  This uses all spiders, insects, bugs, what have you and summons them to you as well.

Comment: I think you're quoting from the Anansi breed book, the Changing Breeds book is only 303 pages long  and on page 60 states that 'Damhan spend one blood point per level of damage, and the healing takes one turn' which means that they can heal up to ten points of damage in a turn

Comment: Everything I quoted was from the W20 book I have.  I didn't even open the Changing Breeds one yet, but I shall now.  However, W20 does say that they don't regenerate, only healing naturally or by blood point.

Comment: A very essential Ananasi gift is Bloodpump (Lvl 3)  Allows the Ananasi to use as much blood per turn as they wish.

Comment: @CrimRei : You may have to hold off for quite a while before you get to rank three. The tradeoff is that you do still have to spend a Gnosis just to uncap your blood use, and hope you have some left (although it is generally harder to get Gnosis back)

Answer (score 0):

I managed to borrow the Anansi breed book from my storyteller to read more about the background and lore and upon noticed that the previous version of 'Replenishment of the Flesh' **can heal aggravated damage as well**.

So I suspect that the designers/writers of the 20th anniversary edition limited the healing effect either to weaken the power, align it to another similar power, or simply made a mistake.

If you feel that it should heal aggravated damage then you would need to ask your storyteller to rule on the effects based upon whichever version suits her better.